# The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

Well I am building a custom control that generates a number of calendars (the calendars are custom not part of any library)  when a date on the calendar is clicked it fills a panel with a kind of day planner.  Now,  all that works so far.  Problem that I am getting occurs when clicking on a hour in the day planner.  A window pops up in the form of a div that creates a form with a cancel and submit button.  When either of these buttons are clicked a custom event is triggered that is suppose to re-initialize the day planner.  I have created a custom event for the day planner but I keep getting the error

"The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases."

Below is the source for reference.

private DayView CreateDayPanner(Control container, DateTime date, int dayNum)
        {
            container.Controls.Clear();

```
        var dv = new DayView(date.Date.AddDays(dayNum))
        {
            Identifier = dayNum,
            LogoPath = "../imgs/dialogueLogo.png",
            fieldClasses = "eDialogue_cls",
            InnerDCls = "innerD_cls",
            FsCCls = "fsContainer_cls",
            LegCCls = "legContainer_cls"
        };
        dv.Submitted += Dv_Submitted;
        dv.Canceled += Dv_Canceled;**
        return dv;
    }
```

The DayView type has the following delegates and handlers:

```
    public delegate void CancelEventHandler(object source, DayViewEventArgs args);

    public delegate void SubmitEventHandler(object source, DayViewEventArgs args);

    public event CancelEventHandler Canceled;
    public event SubmitEventHandler Submitted;


    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        OnSubmitted(StartDate);
        OnCancelled(StartDate);
    }
```

And finally the event is triggered on DayView type as follows:

The cancel button:
            cancel.Attributes.Add(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href.ToString(), csm.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this, StartDate.ToShortDateString()));

The Submit button:

```
        submit.Attributes.Add(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href.ToString(), csm.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this, StartDate.ToShortDateString()));
```

I don't know what is causing that error.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to add the following  code appearing before RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArguments).

Comment: private void OnCancelled(DateTime startDate)
        {
            Canceled?.Invoke(this, new DayViewEventArgs() { Date = startDate });
        }

        private void OnSubmitted(DateTime startDate)
        {
            Submitted?.Invoke(this, new DayViewEventArgs() { Date = startDate });
        }